# Linkedin FunCaptcha error: "Your noCAPTCHA user response code is missing or invalid"

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, linkedin-api, captcha, browser-automation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WND7Dve5OaU

I’m trying to automate Linkedin sign up with puppeteer, but I’m stuck on captcha.

I always get error "Your noCAPTCHA user response code is missing or invalid.", regardless of whether I’m trying to pass it manually ( with clicking on right answers in browser ) or with services like 2captcha on anticaptcha ( but they return a solution token, even if I set my proxy for solving ).

I tried to use different proxies and tried to disable proxies, but nothing helped.

I use random ( but actual ) user agents and stealth plugin. http://bot.sannysoft.com/ is all green, so it’s unlikely Linkedin identify me as bot.

A few months ago I didn't encounter this problem and always successfully passed the captcha.

Correct solution will be necessarily paid.

Comment: I found out that https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs/ give me 0% trust score and detects stealth techniques, so Linkedin probably do the same

Answer (score 7):

LinkedIn CAPTCHA Bug: Your noCAPTCHA user response code is missing or invalid

Solution Worked for Me:

1. Clear the LinkedIn Cookies from your browser.
2. Disconnect your device from your regular network.
3. Connect your device with a different or mobile network.
4. Now open LinkedIn in your device's browser and Sign In.
5. You may not see any CAPTCHA now.
6. After successful Sign In, you can connect to your regular network to use LinkedIn.

Conclusion of the Problem:

1. This is not a browser or extension problem.
2. This may be an unresolved API bug of "Arkose Labs" (CAPTCHA provider of LinkedIn).
3. Disabling Ad and Tracker Blocker didn't work for me.

Let me know if my solution also works for you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the only solution is to reset the password with the [Forgot Password?](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/request-password-reset?trk=homepage-basic_forgot_password) mechanism; Solved it for many of my friends and colleagues.

Comment: Forget Password indeed work, when you try to login from another device either you've to go through Forget Passwd again and again or same error.

Answer (score 0):

I started using VPN Extensions. And my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

— I tried all that, but it still didn't work. However, **resetting my password** through the 'forgot password' link did the trick. Interestingly, even when I re-entered the same LinkedIn password afterwards, it worked perfectly.